# Consuming GraphQL in .NET 4.5 project using C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, http-post, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 project that has a new integration requirement to read data from GraphQL and do some logic.
I've tried searching in google and documentation but couldn't find anything that helps in achieving this.

Things I've tried:

1. I've created a GraphQL server using HotChocolate and tried to consume in the client(.Net 4.5) by making a HttpClient POST request with `Content-Type='application/graphql'` but it is not working. (Throws a 404: Not Found error)
2. I've tried to install the GraphQLClient nuget package to the solution, but it is failing as the framework is not compatible.

Please help me if there is any other way to to consume/query the GraphQL in .Net 4.5 using C#.

Thanks,